# Como puedo hacer un "for line in" en reversa? Que la ultima palabra se procese de primero en BASH script

Tags: bash, script

```
for line in $(cat file)
do
  Extract $line
  if [ "$x" != "false" ]
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done
```

Comment: Iría bien tener un ejemplo de cómo quieres que sea. Yo lo interpreraba como que coges la última palabra, pero @Pat en su buena respuesta considera la última línea

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas, pero si ya que estás usando `cat` para leer el archivo de entrada, bien podrías usar [`tac`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) (la inversa de `cat`), que seguramente ya tienes en el sistema por que forma parte de las `coreutils`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  Extract $line
  if [ "$x" != "false" ]
  then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < <(tac file)
```

Nota que modifiqué la lógica ciclo de lectura por una forma más recomendable. Te sugiero usar: https://www.shellcheck.net/ para verificar el código bash que escribas, se aprende mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, nunca hagas `for linea in $(cat file)`. [Eso se llama "trampa de bash #1"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Es siempre mejor hacer `while IFS= read -r line; do ... ;done < file`.

Eso dicho, para leer el fichero al reves, es decir que la ultima linea se lea primera, haz [lo que te dijo Patricio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/281912/693):

```
tac file | while IFS= read -r linea; do
    ...
done
```

Si quieres leer la ultima palabra primera es mas complejo:

```
$ cat  file
ab cd
ef gh
ij kl
$ tac file
ij kl
ef gh
ab cd
```

Como ves, el `tac` te da la última linea como primera, pero la primera palabra es la penúltima. Es decir, solo inversa el orden de las lineas y no el orden de las palabras dentro de la linea. Si necesitas también cambiar el orden, puedes combinar el `tac` con el `rev` que invierta el orden de su entrada:

```
$ echo 123 | rev
321
```

Combinados:

```
$ cat file
ab cd
ef gh
ij kl

$ tac file | 
    while IFS= read -r linea; do 
        rev<<<"$linea" | 
            while read -r ultima resto; do 
                echo "última: $(rev<<<"$ultima") resto:$resto"
            done
    done
última: kl resto:ji
última: gh resto:fe
última: cd resto:ba
```